# Configuring ng-packagr in "package.json" is deprecated

Tags: angular-cli, ng-packagr

While building an angular 13 package with sub entries, I'm getting the warning below.

```
Building Angular Package
WARNING: Found configuration in ...<PATH_TO_PACKAGE>/package.json.
Configuring ng-packagr in "package.json" is deprecated. Use "ng-package.json" instead.
```

All the relevant info derived from `ng version`

```
Angular CLI: 13.0.4
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.17
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.0.3
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... elements, forms, language-service, material
... material-moment-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1300.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.0.4
@angular-devkit/core            13.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.0.3
@angular/cli                    13.0.4
@schematics/angular             13.0.4
ng-packagr                      13.0.8
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.4.4
```

Any idea if this is a false positive or how to tackle it since official ng-packagr documentation does not mention that usage of ng-packagr inside package.json is deprecated.

Answer (score 12):

You need to extract this from `package.json`

```
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public-api.ts",
    }
  }
}
```

to a new file `ng-package.json` this:

```
{
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

Checked in my library, works for me!

Comment: Thank you for this. Saved me from going nuts. Can you please post a link where this is officially documented?

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution. The solution is well explained in the warning message I'm getting from ng-packagr. What I'm asking for is why official documentation is not aligned with a deprecation message warning. According to the official docs they recommend to the consumers of this library to use ngPackage inside package.json.

Answer (score -1):

Agree above, I think it's just a warning for now, check the commit: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/commit/037ccf5cf30c1680251199b6affb7ecb0c89ee01

Comment: Bring nothing new to the question.

Comment: I've already checked that commit. The question is more oriented on what should we do for the future. Since it is not mentioned in their documentation.